# What are the effects of discount retailers on the suppliers' economics?

Tags: price, technology, discount, retail-economics

The [ACTION retail store](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Action_(store)) is very popular in Europe and usually provides good but cheap quality goods (as people say).

The cheap prices are guaranteed that the bulk part of the store goods is made in cheap labour countries along with other strategies of well-organized management and logistics, simple stores, standardized merchandise, etc.

**Cheaper production** = **cheap labour** and **cheap technology**?

Does cheap technology mean more harm to workers and environment?

Is not the consumers in Europe simply live cheaper because of harder life elsewhere? Should not we better buy more expensive essential goods that guarantee that the workers in cheap-labour countries work and good conditions and are paid well?

**My main question is:**

**What are the effects of discount retailers on the suppliers' economics?**

My question is naive since it is an old story, but these discount retailers have become more popular seems to be during last decades.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: @Giskard The question is there, "What are the effects of discount retailers on the suppliers' economics?" It is a general question. By asking a more precise question in the first place, it would mean that I understand the topics and thus do not need to ask anyone else.

Comment: You pose three separate questions, most of which are very broad. A thorough answer would be very long, and that makes the question a poor fit for the SE format. Also, IMO some of the questions are not very clear, as *harm* and *effect* are very broad terms themselves.